# Targeting a specific multiselect list in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a Multiselect list that I can clear all of the selected items by clicking on the first field in the list (this is an empty value, i.e. "").

I am using this jquery:

```
    $("#States").change(function () {
    var sValue = $(this).val();
    if (sValue == "") {
        $(" option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
    }
    return false;       
});
```

The problem is that this also unselects the items in all my other multiselect list boxes. How do I target a specific list? (probably a very simple question but this is my first foray into jquery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(selector, context)`.

```
$("option:selected", this).prop("selected", false);
```

**Note**: The `val` method for multiple select elements returns an array not a string, so you are comparing an array with a empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You use `$(this)` instead of targetting all selected options:

```
$("option:selected", this).prop("selected", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add context to the selector. See below,

```
$("option:selected", this).removeAttr("selected");
```

Use `.prop` if you are using latest version of jQuery. See other answers for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the element you're using:

```
if (sValue == "") {
    $('option:selected', this).removeAttr("selected");
}
```

Comment: Looks like I was serially downvoted! http://stackoverflow.com/users/367401/benm?tab=reputation

Answer (score 0):

You can target it more by extending the jQuery selector:

```
$("#States option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
```

Comment: ok is it possible to do abstract that out so I can make function more generic? i.e. $(this+ " option:selected")

Comment: @JohnS, sure. See the other answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code will work.

```
$("#States").change(function () {
    var sValue = $(this).val();
    if (sValue == "") {
        $(this).find("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
    }
    return false;       
});
```